# How Can I Use fdt.launch.Application for AIR Projects & FDT 5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, air, fdt

i'm trying to run this on an AIR Mobile project..

```
<fdt.launch.application projectname="TestAndroid" mainclass="src/com/powerflasher/SampleApp/TestAndroid.as" debug="false" target="../bin/TestAndroid.swf" startswf="false" />
```

gives the following error..
fdt.launch.Application does not support AIR Projects.

is there an alternative to this?

Comment: What version of FDT are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

### Yes

FDT 5.5 offers a new 'fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration' task. To enable the execution of launch configurations in an ANT environment.

[Watch a video here.](https://vimeo.com/41847484)

[See documentation here.](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks#fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration_.28FDT_5.5.29)

### No

You it's not exactly the same; however, you have all of the same options available (and more) via the 'fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration' task and launcher GUI combined. The only disadvantage is that this workflow is not as portable. The FDT team is considering offering more options to make it more portable.

[Update] Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710765/how-to-build-a-modular-air-application-with-fdt-5-5/10739095#10739095) for more info on alternatives on building module AIR applications.